# Existing ASP.Net website localization?

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

We have a website that is currently in production and it uses the Arabic language, now i was asked to add English language to the website. The current website is developed with no consideration at all for localization so i am facing tow options now:

Option 1, add a global resource file and change the all the controls to take information for the global resource file.

Option 2, Copy the website and change all the design. (I think it's unreasonable).

Is my analysis right ? 
Is there any other options i am missing, maybe a better way to solve this problem ?